# Import XML with multiple Tables to SQL Server

Tags: xml, ssis, ado.net, sql-server-2012, dataflowtask

I got XML with multiple tables to import to SQL Server
to do this, 
I follow this steps:

- Add data flow task to control flow tab.

On data flow tab (when double clicked the data flow task):

- Add XML source, configure the XML location and XSD location.
- Add Ado.net destination, connect source to destination, Input Output Selection will show up, select table to import to SQL.
- Configure connection Manager.    Under User table or view, click
  "New" button to generate new table to    database where the xml table
  values will be inserted.
- Execute package. New table has added to my database with some values.

**My goal** is to import table to my Database, my problem is I have lots of table from my xml schema, and it will take time to do the steps 2-5 repeatedly. Is there a way to resolve this.

**Note**: I don't have a ready made table on my SQL server that's why I generate new table to my database matched to XML schema. (step 3).

Comment: Is your schema changing frequently or is the table creation just a lazy shorthand for development?

Comment: its just a lazy shorthand for development, it has hundreds of tables, thats why. If I create tables for my schema it will take a really long time. Is there a way, to atleast save time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you described is the fastest / easiest way I know of for this task.

If you look at it from the other end of the telescope, you are:

- shredding a very complex XML schema into separate SQL tables
- generating tables that perfectly match the XML structure, including foreign key relationships
- loading the tables with data
- building a repeatable process
- it's probably taking you under a minute per table
- not having to type anything
- using standardised tools that minimize your test effort

Happy clicking ...

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server supports the `xml` data type. Consider storing your XML data *as* XML data.

SQL Server permits you to query the XML data using XQuery. It even supports indexes over XML, and permits the XML data to be constrained to validating against a particular set of XML schemas.